# Object Jsonp array undefined value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, json

I need help....I have this code:

```
  var req = $.ajax( {
   url:'http://zz33.infoucrso.com/WSCategorias.svc/cargarCategoria?callback=?',
   dataType : "jsonp",
   data: { nombre: val},
   timeout : _timeOut
  });
  req.success(function(datos)
  {
   ProcesarCategorias(datos);
  });
```

So I receive a object JSON and pass that object to the function ProcessarCategotias that have the next code:

```
function ProcesarCategorias(datos) {
 var categoria = JSON.stringify(datos);

 alert(categoria);
}
```

So that show an alert with the next information: {"IdCategoria":2,"Nombre":"Música"}, but I need to access only 
the value of Nombre, if I do categoria[0] this show me an "{", If I do categoria["Nombre"] shows me an undefinied. I saw other questions but that doesn't work for me.
So thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange

```
JSON.stringify(datos)
```

for

```
JSON.stringify(datos['Nombre'])
```